# Всем привет! Подскажите как новичку в чем тут проблема. LNK2005 и LNK1169 (Visual studio)

Tags: c++

Написал простенькую прогу, работала.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Но после, я создал еще один проект в той же папке, и начало выдавать ошибки LNK2005 и LNK1169.Как это исправить?

Comment: Вставляйте, пожалйуста, код в текстовом виде, а не в виде скриншота https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/189027

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор вам понятно объясняет. У вас 2 main функции в 2 cpp файлах